# Exemplary open-source C# / WPF apps

Tags: c#, wpf, open-source, project

I'm looking for a high-quality open-source C# / WPF app to dissect and learn from.
I have about 5 years of C# and WinForms and almost zero WPF experience.
I'm not terribly fussed about the functionality of the app; the WPF paradigm seems markedly different from Winforms and I want to look at an example of how it "should" be done.
Thanks, Alan

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at [BubbleBurst](http://bubbleburst.codeplex.com/), the application that comes along with Josh Smith's [book about MVVM](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/my-e-book-about-advanced-mvvm/).

Answer (score 0):

[Crack.Net](http://www.codeplex.com/cracknetproject) is often cited as a good example of WPF/MVP